# .NET Framework and version Compatibility

Tags: .net, frameworks, .net-4.0, .net-2.0, backwards-compatibility

If .NET application(Form/Web) is built with Framework 2.0, will it work with a computer having only version 4.0 of the framework?

For example I installed a fresh copy of Win Server 2003 and updated the system with v4.0 of the .NET framework(then system had only 1.0, 1.1 and 4.0 of .NET) but when installing SQL Server 2008 R2 Express the setup asked to install yet another v3.5 SP1 of the framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes your 2.0 application will work on the computer which has 4.0 framework. Backward compatibility is there in dot net 4.0.

For more information have a look at this msdn [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx)

MSDN says

> However, in practice, this
> compatibility can be broken by
> seemingly inconsequential changes in
> the .NET Framework and changes in
> programming techniques. For example,
> performance improvements in the .NET
> Framework 4 can expose a race
> condition that did not occur on
> earlier versions. Similarly, using a
> hard-coded path to .NET Framework
> assemblies, performing an equality
> comparison with a particular version
> of the .NET Framework, and getting the
> value of a private field by using
> reflection are not backward-compatible
> practices. In addition, each version
> of the .NET Framework includes bug
> fixes and security-related changes
> that can affect the compatibility of
> some applications and components.

However you need to target the supportedruntime to 4.0 in your 2.0 application configuration file.

Comment: The only breaking changes in .NET were made between 1.1 and 2.0.

Comment: Hardly; the only _major_ breaking changes were made there, but 2.0 -> 4.0 can break things; indeed that's why you have to opt-in.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add an entry to the app.config to opt-in to running on CLRv4.

```
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"  />
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"  />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

(If you don't add the v2 info it will *only* run on the v4 CLR!)